# VSC build task to delete a file and continue if it doesn't exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to write a build task that deletes a file if it exists and not fail if it doesn't?

Using the powershell command `Remove-Item` you can set the error action, but as it still has a non zero exit code the pre-launch tasks stops.

This is my task currently:

```json
{
  "label" : "Clean PRG",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "Remove-Item",
  "args": [ "${workspaceFolder:Display}/test.prg", "-ErrorAction", "SilentlyContinue" ],
  "problemMatcher": [],
},
```